# Doctrine ignores the charset and collation of the databaae

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, collation, charset

When I execute the command `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`, I get the SQL query below to create a table. It uses `utf8` charset and `utf8_unicode_ci` collation.

```
CREATE TABLE an_example
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
 id_user INT NOT NULL, 
 date DATETIME NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However, the database is set to `latin1` and `latin1_swedish_ci`. See below the results from the query that shows the character set and collation of the database.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA  WHERE schema_name = "mydb";
+--------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| CATALOG_NAME | SCHEMA_NAME | DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME | DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME | SQL_PATH |
+--------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| def          | mydb        | latin1                     | latin1_swedish_ci      | NULL     |
+--------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
```

I did set the character set and collation in `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: latin1
        default_table_options:
            collate: "latin1_swedish_ci"
```

I also deleted the cache just in case.

Answer (score 2):

The database settings are only *defaults* for when you create a table without specifying charset/collation.

The table settings are only *defaults* for when you create a column without specifying charset/collation.

I recommend you worry, not about the database (SCHEMATA), but about the table and its columns.